# Treeview but the count of items is displayed behind the text

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Recently I have been tinkering with TreeViews in WinForms and saw a example that I want to recreate to practice.
Here is the example:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcYnt.png)

In the example you will see the count of items behind the text.
I want to recreate the with a TreeView.
The count will be the count of childs of the node.
Is there a way to realise this? Or do I need to make a custom TreeViewControl?

Edit: The example is not a TreeView but a CheckedListbox. But for practice I would like to recreate it with a TreeView.

Comment: I don't see any Treeview in your image!

Comment: What is shown in the example is a listbox but I want to recreate it with a treeview

Comment: You are looking for a mulitcolumn treeview, which is not in the toolbox. or you could choose a fixed font and add a few spaces, but that will hardly look good..